# How to do eager loading properly?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Anyone has any ideas why this query won't get eager-loaded properly? (Finan is loaded eagerly, but Trans/Charge/Purchaser are not.

```
            return session.QueryOver<Plot>()
                .Where(x => x.Project == Project)
                .Fetch(x => x.Trans).Eager
                .Fetch(x => x.Charge).Eager
                .Fetch(x => x.Finan).Eager
                .Fetch(x => x.Purchaser1.User).Eager
                .Future<Plot>();
```

My Mapping:

```
public class PlotMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Plot>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Plot> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References(x => x.Project).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.LazyLoad().Not.Nullable();
        mapping.References(x => x.Finan).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: My Plot Class is something like below:**

```
[Serializable]
public class Plot : BaseEntity<Plot>
{
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual string Plot_No { get; set; }
    public virtual PlotPurchaser Purchaser1 { get; set; }


    public virtual Finan Finan { get; set; }
    public virtual Trans Trans{ get; set; }
    public virtual Charge Charge{ get; set; }
```

Comment: How are you determining that those properties are not being eager-loaded?

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, I am viewing it via NHProf, and the Trans/Charge/Purchaser entities are all loaded individually via Proxy.

Comment: can you post class Plot as well ?

Comment: Hi @frictionlesspulley, I have added Plot class.

Comment: can you look at the differences between the mapping of Finan and Trans/Charge/Purchaser using `AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Foo>().WriteMappingsTo("/Some/Folder");`?